# shell_exec(). Как обработать вывод?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, администрирование

Получаю ответ от shell_exec("screen -list"):

Стараюсь убрать пробелы и разбить полученную строку на массив, чтобы обрабатывать этот массив и получать нужную информацию, но ничего не выходит.

Ни `$shell_res = str_replace(" ", "", shell_exec("screen -list"));`, ни `str_replace()` не убирают пробелы и элементы массива получаются такие:

```
[5] => PM)  (Detached)
    2853.19134      (10/14/2019
[6] => 02:00:47
[7] => AM)  (Attached)
    993.19142       (10/14/2019
```

Что это за символы, как их определить? Есть может-быть какая-то статья, где подробнее рассказывается о всякой работе с командами Linux на php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

shell_exec — выполнить команду через оболочку и вернуть вывод в виде строки. Если хотите проверить, что вы получаете в результате воспользуйтесь var_dump (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php).